# JBOSS JNDI look-up(mail session) ERROR

Tags: jakarta-mail, jndi, jboss6.x

I am developing an application that connects to a java mail session configured in JBOSS. I'm only knowledgeable on how to deploy application for my servers.

In my standalone-full.xml

```
<outbound-socket-binding name="mail-smtp">
  <remote-destination host="localhost" port="25"/>
</outbound-socket-binding>
```

In my domain.xml. Below is configured to the profile for the server being used.

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:mail:1.2">
 <mail-session name="default" jndi-name="java:jboss/mail/Default">
  <smtp-server outbound-socket-binding-ref="mail-smtp"/>
 </mail-session>
 <mail-session name="EmailFilenet" jndi-name="java:jboss/mail/Email">
  <smtp-server ssl="true" outbound-socket-binding-ref="mail-smtp">
    <login name="email" password="pass"/>
  </smtp-server>
 </mail-session>
</subsystem>
```

In my code.

```
Context ictx = new InitialContext();     
mailSession = (Session) ictx.lookup("java:jboss/mail/Email");
MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(mailSession);
message.setSubject(subject);
message.setRecipients(javax.mail.Message.RecipientType.TO,
            javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress.parse(email, false));
message.setText(body);
message.saveChanges();
```

Here's the error:

```
23:44:10,025 INFO  [stdout] (Thread-5 (HornetQ-client-global-threads-
473161222)) javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: 
localhost, port: 465;

23:44:10,025 INFO  [stdout] (Thread-5 (HornetQ-client-global-threads-
473161222))   nested exception is:

23:44:10,025 INFO  [stdout] (Thread-5 (HornetQ-client-global-threads-
473161222))     java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect

23:44:10,025 INFO  [stdout] (Thread-5 (HornetQ-client-global-threads-
473161222))     at 
com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:1972)

23:44:10,025 INFO  [stdout] (Thread-5 (HornetQ-client-global-threads-
473161222))     at 
com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:642)

23:44:10,025 INFO  [stdout] (Thread-5 (HornetQ-client-global-threads-
473161222))     at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:295)

23:44:10,025 INFO  [stdout] (Thread-5 (HornetQ-client-global-threads-
473161222))     at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:176)

23:44:10,025 INFO  [stdout] (Thread-5 (HornetQ-client-global-threads-
473161222))     at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:196)
```

I have checked this guide already.
https://docs.jboss.org/jbossweb/3.0.x/jndi-resources-howto.html
But the web.xml get's erased once the server is turned off. So I don't think it's applicable to me.

Don't I just need to connect the mail session via JNDI then the properties are already set? Why is it attempting to connect the smtp host to localhost and port 465?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve my problem by modifying the remote-destination host and port values in my domain.xml and standalone.xml

Previous config:

```
<outbound-socket-binding name="mail-smtp">
 <remote-destination host="localhost" port="25"/>
</outbound-socket-binding>
```

Updated config:

```
<outbound-socket-binding name="mail-smtp">
 <remote-destination host="smtp.gmail.com" port="465"/>
</outbound-socket-binding>
```

After doing that. I encountered an error with the certificates. So I downloaded an app to extract certificates from gmail and import it to my truststores and keystores. Then everything worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

It's trying to connect to localhost because you told it the server is on localhost (`<remote-destination host="localhost"`).

It's trying to connect to port 465 because you said you wanted to use SSL (`<smtp-server ssl="true"`).

Comment: Thanks @Bill Shannon, do I need to change some of the configs to be able to send mail? I am not sure anymore how to take this forward.

Comment: Well, yes, if the configuration you have isn't correct, you need to change it!  What host do you want it to connect to?  Does that host require SSL?  Update the configuration based on the answer to those questions.